# Sass each loop behaviour in mixin issue

Tags: css, sass

Got a Sass issue which is driving me insane. Basically I have the following Sass code:

```
$breakpoints: mobile 320px, tablet 760px, desktop 960px;

@mixin setbreakpoint($point) {
    @each $breakpoint in $breakpoints {
      @if $point == #{nth($breakpoint, 1)} {
        @media (min-width: #{nth($breakpoint, 2)}) { @content; }
      }
    }
}

.page-wrap {
  width: 75%;
  @include setbreakpoint(mobile) { content:"mobile"; }
  @include setbreakpoint(tablet) { content:"tablet"; }
  @include setbreakpoint(desktop) { content:"desktop"; }
}

@each $breakpoint in $breakpoints {
    .page-wrap-#{nth($breakpoint, 1)} { content:#{nth($breakpoint, 2)}; }
}
```

Which outputs the following css:

```
.page-wrap {
  width: 75%; }
  @media (max-width: 320px) {
    .page-wrap { content: "mobile"; } }
  @media (max-width: 760px) {
    .page-wrap { content: "mobile"; } }
  @media (max-width: 960px) {
    .page-wrap { content: "mobile"; } }
  @media (max-width: 320px) {
    .page-wrap { content: "tablet"; } }
  @media (max-width: 760px) {
    .page-wrap { content: "tablet"; } }
  @media (max-width: 960px) {
    .page-wrap { content: "tablet"; } }
  @media (max-width: 320px) {
    .page-wrap { content: "desktop"; } }
  @media (max-width: 760px) {
    .page-wrap { content: "desktop"; } }
  @media (max-width: 960px) {
    .page-wrap { content: "desktop"; } }

.page-wrap-mobile {
  content: 320px; }

.page-wrap-tablet {
  content: 760px; }

.page-wrap-desktop {
  content: 960px; }
```

Question is:
Why does the mixin each loop produce 9 results where the basic class each loop produces 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of this if statement right here:

```
@if $point == #{nth($breakpoint, 1)} {
    @media (min-width: #{nth($breakpoint, 2)}) { @content; }
}
```

You're comparing variables with different types.  For whatever reason, the compiler always thinks they're equal.  All you have to do is remove the string interpolation and it works as you expect:

```
@if $point == nth($breakpoint, 1) {
    // You don't need when displaying the value either...
    @media (min-width: nth($breakpoint, 2)) { @content; }
}
```